# Android - Independent Fragment UI testing tool

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso, android-uiautomator

I've been looking for a way to test the UI of my Fragments separately (ie, independently from other fragments and activities) but I can't find a way to do it.

In particular, let's say I have Fragment A, Fragment B and Fragment C. The only way (app-wise) to go to Fragment C is by passing through Fragment A and Fragment B first. I am looking for a way to test Fragment C directly (potentially by mocking its dependencies, if any exists), without having to pass through Fragment A and B.

Tools I investigated so far:

- monkey: only used to generate pseudo-random events through command line. Not what I want.
- monkeyrunner: it can run Python programs to send event streams to my Android app, but it cannot target a particular Fragment directly with those scripts.
- Espresso: white-box testing tool. This comes close to what I want, but it still requires passing through Fragment A and B before reaching Fragment C (ie, you need to start your app and then the tests will run from there).
- UI Automator: black-box testing tool. This also comes close, but again, it requires passing through the previous Fragments before testing the one I want (Fragment C).

Is there any way to **test the UI of a Fragmen**t directly?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I'm am using a custom `FragmentTestRule` and Espresso to test each of my `Fragments` in isolation.

I have a dedicated `TestActivity` that shows the tested `Fragments` in my app. In my case the `Activity` only exists in the `debug` variant because my instrumentation tests run against `debug`.

*TL;DR Use the awesome [FragmentTestRule](https://github.com/21Buttons/FragmentTestRule)* library by [@brais-gabin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/842697/brais-gabin).

**1. Create a `TestActivity`** in `src/debug/java/your/package/TestActivity.java` with a content view where the tested `Fragment` will be added to:

```
@VisibleForTesting
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
        frameLayout.setId(R.id.container);
        setContentView(frameLayout);
    }
}
```

**2. Create a AndroidManifest.xml** for the `debug` variant and declare the `TestActivity`. This is required to start the `TestActivity` when testing. Add this Manifest to the `debug` variant in `src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application>           
        <activity android:name="your.package.TestActivity"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**3. Create the `FragmentTestRule`** in the `androidTest` variant at `src/androidTest/java/your/test/package/FragmentTestRule.java`:

```
public class FragmentTestRule<F extends Fragment> extends ActivityTestRule<TestActivity> {

    private final Class<F> mFragmentClass;
    private F mFragment;

    public FragmentTestRule(final Class<F> fragmentClass) {
        super(TestActivity.class, true, false);
        mFragmentClass = fragmentClass;
    }

    @Override
    protected void afterActivityLaunched() {
        super.afterActivityLaunched();

        getActivity().runOnUiThread(() -> {
            try {
                //Instantiate and insert the fragment into the container layout
                FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
                mFragment = mFragmentClass.newInstance();
                transaction.replace(R.id.container, mFragment);
                transaction.commit();
            } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                Assert.fail(String.format("%s: Could not insert %s into TestActivity: %s",
                        getClass().getSimpleName(),
                        mFragmentClass.getSimpleName(),
                        e.getMessage()));
            }
        });
    }
    public F getFragment(){
        return mFragment;
    }
}
```

**4. Then you can test `Fragments`** in isolation:

```
public class MyFragmentTest {

    @Rule
    public FragmentTestRule<MyFragment> mFragmentTestRule = new FragmentTestRule<>(MyFragment.class);

    @Test
    public void fragment_can_be_instantiated() {

        // Launch the activity to make the fragment visible 
        mFragmentTestRule.launchActivity(null);

        // Then use Espresso to test the Fragment
        onView(withId(R.id.an_id_in_the_fragment)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    }
}
```

Comment: the only **"little"** thing is that your test code is mixed with productive/runtime code (at least in debug build) which can easily and very fast get messy as you add more tests to the suite :( Probably workaround if better solution doesn't exist is to leave just manifest entry in debug build and to keep classes (TestActivity, Rule, etc..) in androidTest

Comment: @thaussma Thanks, this solution has solved my problem too. I just want to know that is this a good practice to add `TestActivity` in your project just for testing purposes?

Comment: @ Kavita_p: Usually you want to avoid having any test-only dependencies in production code. Adding `TestActivity` to production breaks this rule. I think the benefits outweights the (small) risk in this case. It's simple and explizit. I think the comment by @Ewoks exaggerates the impact of one Activity and then implies that this could lead to adding lots of other test-dependencies to production. Which is always a bad idea...

Answer (score 4):

I developed [FragmentTestRule](https://github.com/21Buttons/FragmentTestRule) an Andorid library using the [@thaussma's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38393087/842697). It allows you to test your `Fragment`s in isolation.

You just need to add this:

```
@Rule
public FragmentTestRule<?, FragmentWithoutActivityDependency> fragmentTestRule =
    FragmentTestRule.create(FragmentWithoutActivityDependency.class);
```

[More information here](https://medium.com/21buttons-tech/how-to-test-fragments-in-isolation-a7435a4cdc92).

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the Navigation Architecture component and you are using a single activity architecture in your app, you can quickly test each fragment by **Deep linking to the target fragment (with appropriate arguments) at the beginning of the test.**

For example:

```
@Rule
@JvmField
var activityRule = ActivityTestRule(MainActivity::class.java)

protected fun launchFragment(destinationId: Int,
                             argBundle: Bundle? = null) {
    val launchFragmentIntent = buildLaunchFragmentIntent(destinationId, argBundle)
    activityRule.launchActivity(launchFragmentIntent)
}

private fun buildLaunchFragmentIntent(destinationId: Int, argBundle: Bundle?): Intent =
        NavDeepLinkBuilder(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext)
                .setGraph(R.navigation.navigation)
                .setComponentName(MainActivity::class.java)
                .setDestination(destinationId)
                .setArguments(argBundle)
                .createTaskStackBuilder().intents[0]
```

destinationId being the fragment destination id in the navigation graph. Here is an example of a call that would be done once you are ready to launch the fragment:

```
launchFragment(R.id.target_fragment, targetBundle())

private fun targetBundle(): Bundle? {
    val bundle = Bundle()
    bundle.putString(ARGUMENT_ID, "Argument needed by fragment")
    return bundle
}
```

Doing it this way will launch the fragment directly. If your test works, then this proves that your app won't crash when the fragment is deep-linked to. It also ensures that the app will be stable if the process is killed by the system and it tries to rebuild the stack and relaunch the fragment.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Robotium](https://github.com/robotiumtech/robotium).This is for android UI testing.

Comment: But Robotium has the same problem as UI Automator and Espresso. In order to test Fragment C, I need to pass through Fragment A and B first. I want a tool that allows me to test Fragment C directly.

Comment: As i have been using robotium,it solves any kind of UI testing problem.I dont know the details of your requirement ,so please check robotium API http://robotium.googlecode.com/svn/doc/com/robotium/solo/Solo.html

Comment: @Tiago I hope APIs like waitForFragmentByTag, waitForFragmentById can help you.  Good luck.