# How to start Fragment directly for espresso test instead of activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-testing, android-espresso

I am running some espresso tests. 
My problem is instead of opening the Main.activity, i want to open the fragment directly which is part of main activity before starting tests.

Comment: Try this  : https://stackoverflow.com/a/38393087/1562755

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The purpose of fragment is to run alongside Activity.
If you want, you can create an empty activity who just run your fragment and his layout, and then put that activity as your MainActivity in the manifest

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a `FragmentManager` transaction in your test.

If you are using [ActivityTestRule](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/rule/ActivityTestRule.html) in your test it is possible to obtain started activity with `getActivity()` and then swap or add the fragment the same way it is done in the production code.